# Sitefinity MVC Feather Widgets - prevent caching

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

I'm using the feather package and building feather widgets for Sitefinity 9.1. I can't seem to override the Output Cache for the widgets using the OutputCache attribute: `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]`. I don't want to have to disable caching at the page level, just at the widget level. How do I disable caching at the widget level in Sitefinity?

Comment: Have you found a working solution yet please?

Answer (score 1):

Better do it on the client-side, especially given that the Sitefinity's team is doing exactly that in the Login Status feather widget which should not be output cached:

The View contains two divs that are initially hidden and shown via javascript on the client depending on the status of the user (which is retrieved via web service):

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Identity/Mvc/Views/LoginStatus/LoginStatus.LoginName.cshtml

The js code:

https://github.com/Sitefinity/feather-widgets/blob/master/Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Identity/Mvc/Scripts/LoginStatus/login-status.js

**EDIT**: What you can try is to subscribe to the **PageManager.Executing** event and see if the page that was changed was your parent/group page. If so, then you can get all its child pages (PageData) with the API and increase their **BuildStamp** property with 1. This will invalidate their cache.
More info here: http://docs.sitefinity.com/tutorial-subscribe-to-events-using-dataprovider-or-manager-class

Comment: Unfortunately, client-side is not an option for us, since the widget content needs to be SEO friendly.

Comment: Maybe if you provide more details it would be easier to find alternatives. For instance what is the nature of the data - is it confidential per user or is it something that just changes frequently, like a share price?

Actually both of the above cases are not SEO friendly, so wondering what the details are.

Comment: It is public facing data --the header and footer for a template. Basically the header and footer can inherit data defined as custom fields in a parent page group/page node. When the data is changed at the parent page, it is not reflected in the child pages, since those child pages are not removed from cache.

Comment: I assume you are using a custom MVC widget for the header and footer and that widget takes the custom field value from the parent page and does something with it.

I updated my answer above

Comment: that solution seemed to work. However, it would be nice if widgets could just support outputcache attribute.

Comment: Agree that that would be nice to have. Please mark as answer if it worked for you

Comment: actually, updating the build stamp for the pages messed up module builder, so I ended up going with some code using CacheDependency and that is working, but your idea of listening for PageManager got me started, thanks!

Comment: Would like to understand in what way the build stamp messed the module builder. Good that you found a solution though

Comment: I believe that module builder is creating pages when a new dynamic module is initialized. In this code, it loses a reference to the page because the build stamp has changed. It throws a null reference exception.

Comment: but you change the build stamp on front end pages only, right, not backend pages?

Comment: Yes, but it also appears to be creating a front end page for widget display or something in module builder...

Comment: It creates only a widget for displaying the data on the front-end, but not the page, probably something else was going on there